# word replacement with accent "Événement" by "Missions et PAD" not working but word replacement is OK

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I try to replace the Menu Title "Événement" by "Missions et PAD". But it is not working.
I tried different word replacements and they are working well. Is it due to the accents ? to a bad coding ? 
I am using CiviCRM for wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For word replacements you often have to use the english word as the original word, so you would put:

Events => Missions et PAD

For menu entries you can also edit it at Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Navigation menu. Right-click on Events and edit it to change the title.

Comment: Great ! Thank you for your clear explanations. Have a great week-end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this method is that a word in a help text for example is no longer displayed in French but only in English with a French word replaced.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean but agree in general that word replacements isn't meant for replacing large amounts of text. Originally it wasn't meant for translation at all, it was meant for english replacement of english words, like replacing Contributions with Payments. So it may not work well in all situations. An alternative for non-english is to use your own .mo file with your changes. You can create .mo files using gettext and the .po files from https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/tree/master.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how to custom translation. Is there a detailed explanation for that ?
I agree that it was meant for english replacement of english words. Perhaps we should adapt the help text in French to that effect.